# How do i get the values in different rows in excel using formuale?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a string of numbers which are spaced randomly in a single cell like this -:

```
"8  29  30 36  32  16 16 33  36 30  1  32 1  2  0  4  21  11  35 17  419 47  14 13  30 36 35 23 27 14  35 20 36 28 44  16 4 4 32 22 0  28 16 27 27 27  30 12 10 34 8  17 19 1 24 17  8"
```

I want this to put individual numbers in different rows starting from 1 to n (total numbers) using a generalized formuale but not able to write the formulae. Could anyone help me please?

Any help would really be appreciated as I am not able to do this!

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: I have tried writing S.No. in left row and try to find index of space so that I can then use the Mid formuale (as i will e getting the start & end index of number) but I am not able to implement it. Could you please help me Sir?

Comment: is it maximum double digits or are you expecting longer numbers?

Comment: Just use this formula   =FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y")

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use VBA at all, the following formula will work.

Assuming the string you mention is in `A1`, put the following formula into `E4`:

```
=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"  "," ")," ","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y")
```

It's a bit of a hack, but it works. There are two elements. Firstly, I notice that you have some numbers separated by double-spaces and I assume that's just padding. Those are removed using the `SUBSTITUTE(A1,"  "," ")`. Secondly, the result is then altered, using `SUBSTITUTE` - changing each space into XML tags which are then parsed using `FILTERXML` into an array.

[image]

As Ed points out, you can use Excel's `TRIM` function which removes multiple spaces more robustly and elegantly:

```
=FILTERXML("<x><y>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ","</y><y>")&"</y></x>","//y")
```

If you're using Office365, then you could use the purpose-built `TEXTSPLIT` function instead.

Comment: use TRIM instead of your substitute and then the number of spaces does not matter as the spacing will become standardized

Comment: Good spot - after all these years I hadn't noticed that difference between Excel TRIM and vba TRIM.

Comment: Side note: It's *mostly* a benefit *(sometimes a caveat)* that Excel's `FilterXML()` function converts node values which can be interpreted as numbers or dates internally to doubles and dates when executing the XPath search (afaik considering only the regional settings for decimals and date formatting). @CLR

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by selecting the cell with the numbers, navigating to the Data tab, and selecting "text to columns".  Select "Delimited" in the window that pops up and choose next.  then select "spaces".  that should work!

Comment: I need formuale to calculate this automatically instead everytime splitting it into different columns using Text-to-Columns feature. Could you write a formuale for that? Like in left row, we will write S.No. from 1 to 40 (just example), and then using those serial numbers to calculate the no space elements and using Mid formulae.

Comment: If you are looking to speed up the process, It might be easiest to record the process of using the delimiter as a macro and then programming a keyboard shortcut to run that macro.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to FILTERXML presented by CLR
Lets assume your string of numbers is sitting in cell D2

1. Standardize the spacing

Use the `TRIM` function to eliminate all excess spacing.

```
TRIM($D$2)
```

2. Add a starting and ending space

Make is so all the numbers are the same in the sense that they all have a single space before and after them.  Regular patterns are nicer to deal with as you do not need to make special cases.  ie first number or last number in the list.  Note this is done after the TRIM function performed.

```
=" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "
```

3. Add start and end identifiers

While potentially not necessarily required, it may make life easier.  Lets use S for start and F for finish.  This can be done with the `SUBSTITUTE` function.  The last optional entry of the substitute function allows you to declare which instance of the search item you which to replace.  This will be convenient for us as we can use a counter to jump are way along the list to the appropriate spaces.  The formula for just adding the S looks like

```
=SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))
```

ROW(A1) is our counter so in this case the first  space will be replaced by S.  Now to put in the F we want to put it in the next space after that S substitution as been made.  Since there is now one less space in the text, the same occurrence number gets used.  The formula becomes:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1))
```

4. Determine number length

This can be done by finding the position of F and S in the string and taking the difference of there position and subtracting 1.  The formula for doing this is:

```
=FIND("F",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-1
```

5. Pull the number

Since we now know where the number start due to the S and we know how many digits there are, you can use the `MID` function to pull the number as a string.  The formula will now look like:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","D",ROW(A1)),FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))+1,FIND("F",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-1)
```

6. End of list

You can copy the last formula down as far as you like and it will generate a list.  However when you copy it down further than the number of numbers you have it will start to through #VALUE! error.  If you do not want to see this and would prefer a blank cell, then you can wrap the above formula in an IFERROR function that can generate "", 0, or "Custom Message".

```
=IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","D",ROW(A1)),FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))+1,FIND("F",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-1),"")
```

7. Text or Number

As it currently stands, the formula above is all string manipulation so your output will be digits stored as text or a string.  If you want to have the digits as a number instead of text then you either have to wrap the MID function in the `VALUE` function or send the resulting text from the MID function through a math operation that will not change its value.  (ie. *1, /1, +0, -0) Alternatively you can simply place a double minus (--) in from of the MID function.  The alternative approach is shown below:

```
=IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","D",ROW(A1)),FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))+1,FIND("F",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-FIND("S",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(" "&TRIM($D$2)&" "," ","S",ROW(A1))," ","F",ROW(A1)))-1),"")
```

[image: POC]